# This script is only accessible from localhost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, symfony, routes, virtualhost

I have a working project with Symfony2.
One of my bundles works well by default but when I activate `mod_rewrite` I get

> This script is only accessible from localhost

This happens only with the routes configured on this bundle, others work fine with `mod_rewrite`

Here is my vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my_application.my_domain.net
    ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.xxx

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/my_application/web"
    <Directory /var/www/my_application/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where can that come from ?

---

### Update

**Example**

I'm getting the error when trying to access

```
my_application.my_domain.net/config/list/produit
```

If I disable `mod_rewrite` I can access

```
my_application.my_domain.net/app.php/config/list/produit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you hitting app_dev.php or config.php?

By default, both of those restrict connections from anywhere but localhost and display that exact same message.

## Update

After the update, I think the problem may be because you have MultiViews enabled. MultiViews can try to load config.php even if it is just referenced as config. Try removing that and see if it helps improve anything.

Comment: I have just added my IP to config.php and I see that `config.php` if displayed instead of my standard routed path (without css).

Comment: Can you give an example of the URL you are using which is failing. It's possible there is a conflict with the route and something else.

Comment: That was it !!!!! Removing `MultiViews` did the trick. Thank you very much, I was having this problem since months.